# How to limited JSON API WordPress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, wordpress

I want use WordPress to create a website, and I want export the site posts with `JSON API`.

I want to limit displayed posts by category but when click this link: `get_category_posts` (JSON API plugin in wordpress setting), I get this error:

> {"status":"error","error":"Include 'id' or 'slug' var in your request."}

`get_category_posts` link : [link](http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_category_posts).

How can I limit posts by category in JSON API WordPress plugin?

Comment: You should ask this on your plugin's page...

Comment: @Random, can you help me more?

Comment: You are talking about a Wordpress Plugin. For each wordpress plugin, there is a forum to ask questions about the plugin, and a FAQ. Here, you don't use the method "get_category_posts" correctly, since the plugin asks you to add id or slug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've neglected to specify which category you actually want;

```
http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_category_posts=1
```

Correctly returns the data for category one for example.

I'm assuming you are using the plugin I've linked to below, you can use either the category ID or the slug.  But you need to specify a category.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#Method:-get_category_posts

Comment: this link `http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_category_posts=1`, show me all of post. i have 9 posts and when use above link and change poste=2 or 3 or another categories, show me all of post !

Comment: I really need this, please help me my dear friend